# Application password still works even after user is disabled / expired

Tags: rest-api, password

we have found that username + application password still successfully authenticate even when the user is disabled / expired. Is this the correct behavior? We would think application passwords would stop working when the user itself cannot login with their WordPress username / password.

Comment: How are you expiring or disabling users? Disabling/expiring users is not a built-in feature of WordPress, so if you're using a plugin for that feature then it's the plugin's responsibility to handle disabling application passwords.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the site is indeed using a plugin: https://memberpress.com

Comment: You'll need to raise this issue with its developers then. Third party plugins are off topic and this sounds like an issue they need to resolve in their plugin anyway.